# Nativescript bare webview doesnt seem to work

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

i recently got into nativescript, and i'm facing a problem that i cant seem to work around it.

What i want to accomplish is to just open a basic WebView and set an external url to load such as stackoverflow.com.

I'm running this on emulator with *Android api 17*

**app.js**

```
var application = require("application");
application.mainModule = "main-page";
application.cssFile = "./app.css";
application.start();
```

**main-page.js**

```
var vmModule = require("./main-view-model");
var webViewModule = require("ui/web-view");
var webView = new webViewModule.WebView();

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var web = page.getViewById(webViewModule.WebView,"webView");
    web.url="http://google.com";

}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
  <StackLayout>
    <WebView id="webView" colSpan="4" row="2"/>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

i also checked the if the INTERNET permission is set to application , and yes its enabled.

Also application stops working, and the command

**tns run android --emulator**

after successfully installing and running the application on emulator it just spams with a lot of output.

Can you help me to understand how exactly is supposed to be working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## tl;dr for others having problems with WebView

For some reason **you can't put a WebView in a StackLayout**, it simply does not show. Use a GridLayout instead. There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/224) on this.

## Full answer

The Android emulator is really chatty but somewhere in that log (most probably in the end) there's almost certainly a stack trace with the error. If you're running a Mac, the iOS emulator is much less chatty.

That said, let's fix your code. Below is working code, commented to show the changes to your code.

**app.js**

No problem there, looking as it should!

**main-page.js**

```
/**
 * Do you actually have a file called 'main-view-model.js' in the same
 * folder as this file? In any case, it's not used in your example code
 * so I commented it out.
 */
//var vmModule = require("./main-view-model");
var webViewModule = require("ui/web-view");

/**
 * Here you are creating a NEW webview. If you want to, you can create
 * element dynamically and then attach them to the view. However, in your
 * example you already have a webview in your xml file so there's no need
 * to create a new one.
 */
//var webView = new webViewModule.WebView();

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    /**
     * Corrected the line below. What you're doing here is pretty
     * much equal to $('#webView') in jQuery. You're selecting
     * an element
     */
    var web = page.getViewById("webView");
    //var web = page.getViewById(webViewModule.WebView,"webView");
    web.url = "http://google.com";

}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <GridLayout>
        <WebView id="webView" />
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

So I've done a couple of things here. First, I've removed the `colSpan="4" row="2"`. Those two parameters are only used for [GridLayouts](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/layouts/grid-layout/HOW-TO.html), and you're using a StackLayout. *However* as you can see I've changed your StackLayout into a GridLayout. Reason for this is that for some reason you can't put a WebView in a StackLayout, it simply does not show. There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/224) on this.

### Alternative solution

If all you want to do is to create a WebView showing Google, you can just set the `url` property directly in the XML. If you're doing it this way you don't even need the Javascript. Of course, if you want to dynamically set the url you need to do it from the Javascript.

Example of setting url property:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <GridLayout>
        <WebView id="webView" url="http://www.google.com" />
    </GridLayout>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attribute url is currently deprecated for WebView. Use src instead.