# How to use nativescript's WebView in angular2?

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to insert a **web-view** on my page and listen the 'loadFinishedEvent'...
But for do this, i need to find the webview in my **component** (ts file), through nativescript way i need to wrap my xml (UI) with a tag:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd
```

But doing this i got this error: 
"*TypeError: this.page.frame._getNavBarVisible is not a function*", and without the Page tag i've already tried with some ways but with unsuccessful...

I do not found any sample of this too, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your .ts file containing class implementation

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
selector: "Date",
templateUrl: "myPage.html", //here is your reference to html page
})

export class Angular2WebView {
//any class function
}
```

Your html file myPage.html

```
<GridLayout>
    <WebView id="webView" url="http://www.google.com" >
    </WebView>
</GridLayout>
```

for more info. refer here [Nativescript bare webview doesnt seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30482269/nativescript-bare-webview-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 1):

Good link for documentation for using [WebView Nativescript/Android](http://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/web-view)

html:

```
 <WebView #webview [src]="url"></WebView>
```

backend code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {WebView, LoadEventData} from "ui/web-view";

@Component({
    selector: 'basic-web-view-component',
    templateUrl: //see html above
})

export class BasicWebViewComponent implements OnInit {

    public url="https://www.google.com";
    @ViewChild("webview") webview: WebView;

    ngOnInit() {

        this.webview.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function (args: LoadEventData) {
             console.log("loadFinishedEvent called");
        });
    }
}
```

Note:  that it seems that WebView needs to sized with width/height attributes are in a GridView, see the docs reference above.  It won't dynamically grow based on content.

Comment: the component code is not the backend code, but rather still the frontend.

Comment: Yes backend is an unfortunate phrase ... but the code file behind the HTNL fie is often called the backing code.   What is a better term ?

Comment: From we development, I like to call this kind of code the "backend of the frontend." This seems to help non-developers understand how the web frontend is growing in complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with the following code:

`<WebView [src]="url" (loadFinished)="loadFinished($event)"></WebView>`

Important: remove the `<Page>` tag (should not be used within Nativescript/Angular 2).

More info: [github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/281)

Comment: Thanks, and also you can use ViewChild decorator to aplly custom settings to native component that is not wokring don't know why..

Comment: Wrap your webviews in GridViews or they may not show up on iOS devices

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the eventargs on load with the method getViewById to find a control. You can find more information here - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/ui-with-xml

Comment: Does not work, because the "angular way" of do that...
I'm already solve it by doing:
<WebView [src]="url" (loadFinished)="loadFinished($event)"></WebView>

And removing the "Page" tag (that should not be used with nativescript/Angular 2

More info at: [link](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/281)

Comment: @RichardSilveira can you expand your comment into an answer