# Nativescript WebView in code only

Tags: angular, webview, nativescript

I'm trying to create a webview to load some pages in the background and perform some javascript injections.

I created a class, which holds the webview, when I call the constructor, it will log the init messages, but the webview does not start, at least, it appears that way because the WebView.loadFinishedEvent is never fired:

```
import { WebView, LoadEventData} from "ui/web-view";

export class LoaderComponent {
    webView: WebView;

    constructor() {
        console.log("Starting loader");
        this.webView = new WebView();
        this.webView.on(WebView.loadFinishedEvent, function (args: LoadEventData) {
            let message;
            if (!args.error) {
                message = "WebView finished loading " + args.url;
            } else {
                message = "Error loading " + args.url + ": " + args.error;
            }
            console.log(message);
        });
        this.webView.url = "https://www.google.com";
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try this http://plugins.nativescript.org/plugin/nativescript-advanced-webview else look at this , http://stackoverflow.com/a/40441231/4712391 and maybe use ngOnInit?

Comment: Hi @TinusJackson, thanks but I'm trying to use the webview component without the need to display it on a page in the foreground. I want to do some loading in the background. And SFSafariViewController does not allow javascript injection or URL interception, so that's not an option.