# Typescript doesn't typecast webview?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webview, electron

I'm using typescript from my project, but it doesn't recognize webviews. For example:

```
const webview = <webview> document.getElementById("foo");
```

Just spits out an error that it "cannot find name 'webview'". How do I resolve this? When works fine when just using javascript.

Note: I'm using Electron webview not NativeScript WebView.

Answer (score 1):

You should include the declaration of webview in your typescript file, so the TS compiler can recognize it :

```
import { WebView } from "ui/web-view";
```

(note that the type is WebView and not webview)

To get the element, there are 'better' ways to get the element. You can refer to the answers of this question : [How to use nativescript's WebView in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734420/how-to-use-nativescripts-webview-in-angular2)